# Zero set of a $C^1$ fuction is countable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ a function of class $C^1$ such that $Df(x)$ is invertible for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:f(x)=0\}$ is a countable set.

My attemp:

I prove that, if $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that, if $x\in B_{\delta}(a)$ then $f(x)\neq f(a)$.

Comment: From what you proved, you can show that in a closed ball, $f$ can only have a finite number of zeros (using Bolzano-Weierstrass).

Comment: Could you be more specific? How can I prove that? Thank you.

Comment: Let $B$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, eg a closed ball. Assume there exists infinitely many $x \in B$ such that $f(x)=0$. Then there exists an injective convergent sequence $x_n$ of elements of $B$ such that $f(x_n)=0$. Let $y$ be the limit, then there exists an open ball $B’$ of $y$ such that $y$ is the only zero of $f$ in $B’$. Since $x_n$ goes to $y$, $x_n \in B$ from a certain point, thus since $f(x_n)=0$, $x_n=y$. A contradiction since $x$ is an injective sequence. So you say that $f$ has finitely many zeros with norm between $0$ and $1$, between $1$ and $2$ and so on...

Comment: Thanks! It's very clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a supplement of @Mindlack's comment. Let us consider for each $n\ge 1$,
$$
\mathcal C_n =\{x\in\Bbb R^n: f(x) = 0,\ \|x\|\le n\}.
$$ By inverse mapping theorem, for each $x\in \mathcal C_n$, there exists $\delta_x>0$ such that $$
B(x,\delta_x)\cap \mathcal{C}_n =\{x\}.
$$ Since $\mathcal C_n$ is compact and $\{B(x,\delta_x)\cap \mathcal C_n:x\in\mathcal C_n\}$ forms an open cover of $\mathcal C_n$, there exists a finite subcover $\{B(x_i,\delta_{x_i})\cap \mathcal C_n:i=1,2,\ldots, N\}$ such that
$$
\mathcal C_n = \bigcup_{i=1}^N\ \big(B(x_i,\delta_{x_i})\cap \mathcal C_n \big)=\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}.
$$ This shows for each $n\ge 1$, $\mathcal{C}_n$ is finite, hence
$$
\{x\in\Bbb R^n : f(x) = 0\} =\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \mathcal C_n 
$$ is at most countable.

Comment: Beautiful explanation! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Gerschgorin You're welcome. I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $Z$ be the zero set of $f.$ If $Z$ were uncountable, it would have a limit point $a\in \mathbb R^n.$ Thus there would exist a sequence of distinct points $x_k\in Z$ converging to $a.$ By the continuity of $f,$ $a\in Z.$ But that contradicts your statement "if $x\in B_{\delta}(a)$ then $f(x)\neq f(a)$."